# Unique Item Cards in Bang?

Tags: bang

Can you play an item card (like a Barrel) if you don't already have one, but someone else does?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables -- Quite correct, and so marked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly you can.  Per the rules:

> no player can ever have two identical
>   cards face up in front of him.

There is no restriction on an identical card being face up in front of *another* person!

Comment: Doh!  We were reading "in front of him" as "on the table"...

Comment: Actually there is a character from an expansion that causes other players to discard an item if he plays the same item.